# Is there any way to convert 'AI' and 'EPS' to corel draw format (.cdr)?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, corel-draw, file-format

Is there any way to convert 'AI' and 'EPS' to corel draw format (.cdr)?

My client want to rework from their existing AI and EPS to corel draw.

Comment: .eps files should merely open in Draw.

Answer (score 3):

As Scott mentions, you can open `.eps` files from Corel Draw.

You just need to re-save them in CD as `.cdr`.

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to do it,  you can:

1. Create a press ready PDF and import it to corel. (make sure to
   convert the text to outsides and unchek the "embed" option)
2. This 2nd method will depend on what versions you have of both
   softwares, usually in CorelDraw you can easily go to "Import" and select
   "PS Interpreted" and select the AI file.    Note that you might need
   to google what are the AI versions that your current version of Corel can
   open, and if is lower, then you can save your Illustrator in an older
   version until it opens.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

In corel Draw X6 or higher versions you can easily import `*.ai` files.
Just go to `File` menu and `Import` then choose `*.ai` in the file format drop down list.

***As simple as 1, 2, 3.***

**Good luck !!!**

Answer (score 0):

You can Import EPS / AI file directly in Corel Draw. There are less possibilities of export to CDR from AI / PSD.